# How to login to joomla.com as a super adminstrator?

Tags: administrator, installation, joomla.com

I am new to joomla.

I have logged in to `https://www.joomla.com/my`  and clicked the `Access Admin` on my respective site.

I tried to install a new template and i was instructed to install new template on extension manager, but extension manager is not showing for me.

When i searched in internet, it get to know i dont have super administrator rights?

How to login as super user in joomla to install my template?

Comment: do you have credentials of admin login? your client might have created a user for you with limited rights

Comment: @Lisa I am the one who created the site

Comment: ok then are your login details the same as the one you created during Joomla installation?

Comment: @Lisa No i haven't installed joomla. I have created new site in joomla.com as vinoth,joomla.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case,

Joomla.com doesn't give super user permissions and there is limited access to everything. You cannot install any extension or template. You have to use the pre-defined template the one you chose during launching your website in `joomla.com`.

**Refer this for more:**

> http://tutorials.joomla.com/no-category/34-joomla-com-admin

Hope this helps